# Trying show another view but can only dismiss existing views - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working on a sign up page. I want to show the main view after the sign up process is finished, but I have a problem like this;
OnBoardingView presents the SignUp view and when the signup process is finished, I update the currentUser. When I debug, the if statement works and the line where the main view is executed, but I see the first step of the signUp view presented by the onboardingView on the screen. As if only opened sheets are closed.

I draw the situation https://i.imgur.com/bUJF1Rv.png

ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appEnvironment: AppEnvironment
    
    var body: some View {
        if appEnvironment.currentUser == nil {
            OnboardingView()
        } else {
            MainView()
        }
    }
}
```

SignUpService

```
final class SignUpService {
    static let shared = SignUpService()
    
    func completeSignUp() async {
        let progress = SignUpProgress.shared
        let auth = FirebaseManager.shared.auth
        
        guard
            let email = progress.email,
            let password = progress.password,
            let photoData = progress.profilePhotoData
        else { return }
        
        do {
            let result = try await auth.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)
            let photoUrl = try await result.user.saveProfilePhoto(data: photoData)
            progress.profileImageUrl = photoUrl
            
            if let userDetail = progress.createSaveUserDetailModel() {
                try await result.user.saveUserDetail(userDetail)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    AppEnvironment.default.currentUser = result.user
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Last Page of the SignUp Steps where I call the SignUpService:

```
//Other things

func didContinueTapped() {
    SignUpProgress.shared.disinterests = Array(selecteds)
    showIndicator = true
    Task(priority: .background) {
        await SignUpService.shared.completeSignUp()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.showIndicator = false
        }
    }
}

//Other things
```

AppEnvironment:

```
final class AppEnvironment: ObservableObject {
    static let `default` = AppEnvironment()
    @Published var currentUser: User?
}
```

Main:

```
@main
struct AnApp: App {
    @StateObject var appEnvironment: AppEnvironment = .default
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(appEnvironment)
        }
    }
}

final class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We really need to see `AppEnvironment` as well, as that is controlling things.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same instantiation of `AppEnvironment`? Is `User` a struct?

Comment: @Yrb Yes, when I debug the if statement inside the ContentView works and enter the else but just dismiss the presentations not show the MainView.

Comment: @Yrb User from Firebase library btw

Comment: @Yrb I added an image for the situation.

Comment: Still can't solve this, any idea?

Comment: I realize you added `AppEnvironment`, but you missed the rest of my comment. You really need to post a minimal reproducible example. That means we can copy and paste your code, and then run it ourselves. You have not posted that. It is impossible to debug this without it.